# Optionally override request culture via url/route in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Application

Tags: routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to override the culture of the current request. I got it working partly using a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```cs
public sealed class LanguageActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> localizationOptions;

    public LanguageActionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> options)
    {
        if (loggerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));

        if (options == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(LanguageActionFilter));
        localizationOptions = options;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string culture = context.RouteData.Values["culture"]?.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(culture))
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Setting the culture from the URL: {culture}");

#if DNX46
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
#else
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
#endif
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

On the controller I use the `LanguageActionFilter`.

```cs
[ServiceFilter(typeof(LanguageActionFilter))]
[Route("api/{culture}/[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

This works so far, but I have two issues with it:

1. I don't like having to declare `{culture}` on every controller, as I am going to need it on every route.
2. I having a default culture doesn't work with this approach, even if I declare it as `[Route("api/{culture=en-US}/[controller]")]` for obvious reasons.

Setting a default route results is not working neither.

```cs
app.UseMvc( routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultRoute",
        template: "api/{culture=en-US}/{controller}"
    );
});
```

I also investigated in a custom `IRequestCultureProvider` implementation and add it to the `UseRequestLocalization` method like

```cs
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        new UrlCultureProvider()
    },
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("de-de"),
        new CultureInfo("en-us"),
        new CultureInfo("en-gb")
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("de-de"),
        new CultureInfo("en-us"),
        new CultureInfo("en-gb")
    }
}, new RequestCulture("en-US"));
```

but then I don't have access to the routes there (I assume cause the routes are done later in the pipeline). Of course I could also try to parse the requested url. And I don't even know if I could change the route at this place so it would match the above route with the culture in it.

Passing the culture via query parameter or changing the order of the parameters inside the route is not an option.

Both urls `api/en-us/products` as we as `api/products` should route to the same controller, where the former don't change the culture.

The order in which the culture will be determined should be

1. If defined in url, take it
2. If not defined in url, check query string and use that
3. If not defined in query, check cookies
4. If not defined in cookie, use `Accept-Language` header.

2-4 is done via `UseRequestLocalization` and that works. Also I don't like the current approach having to add two attributes to each controller (`{culture}` in route and the `[ServiceFilter(typeof(LanguageActionFilter))]`).

**Edit:**
I also like to limit the number of valid locales to the one set in `SupportedCultures` property of the `RequestLocalizationOptions` passed to the `UseRequestLocalization`.

`IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> localizationOptions` in the `LanguageActionFilter` above doesn't work as it returns a new instance of `RequestLocalizationOptions` where `SupportedCultures` is always `null` and not the one passed to the.

FWIW it's an RESTful WebApi project.

Comment: So as far as I understand from your question, you're wanting to get that url route working, yeah? What about if you define two routes? One with `{culture}` and one without it?

Comment: Not just that, I'd like to avoid using the `LanguageActionFilter` for several reasons, one is that I have to repeat it over on each controller and the other being I don't have access to `RequestLocalizationOptions`. As you can see in the example I tried injecting it, but I always get the default `RequestLocalizationOptions` version with `SupportedCultures` being null, not the one that's got passed to the request localization middleware

Comment: Adding `api/{controller}` and `api/{culture=en-US}/{controller}` inside `app.UseMvc( routes =>  ... )` doesn't work

Comment: I guess one way to do it is to create an `IRouter` if you want access to routes. Personally though, I'd recommend that you tap into `UseRequestLocalization` and add a custom `IRequestCultureProvider`. Like you said, you will not be able to access the routes from there so you would need to parse it yourself but you can rewrite the path at this stage so you can then re-execute `/api/{controller}` to `/api/en-us/{controller}`. Your MVC route handlers will pick up on that rewritten path.

Comment: Looks like RC2 will include an extension method [`HttpContext.GetRouteData`](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions/RoutingHttpContextExtensions.cs). You should then be able to use the routes (The one with the culture parameter will also require a constraint to differentiate from the default route) and create a custom `IRequestCultureProvider`, since you can inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` service and then use that extension method to get the route data.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update ASP.Net Core 1.1**

A new `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` is coming as part of the 1.1 [release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/), which hopefully means you won't have to create your own request provider anymore. You might still find the information here useful (like the routing bits) or you might be interested in creating your own request culture provider.

---

You can create 2 routes that will let you access your endpoints with and without a culture segment in the url. Both `/api/en-EN/home` and `/api/home` will be routed to the home controller. (So `/api/blah/home` won't match the route with culture and will get 404 since the blah controller doesn't exists)

For these routes to work, the one that includes the culture parameter has higher preference and the culture parameter includes a regex:

```c#
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "apiCulture",
        template: "api/{culture:regex(^[a-z]{{2}}-[A-Z]{{2}}$)}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "defaultApi",
        template: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");                

});
```

The above routes will work with MVC style controller, but if you are building a rest interface using wb api style of controllers, the attribute routing is the favored way in MVC 6.

- One option is to use attribute routing, but use a base class for all your api controllers were you can set the base segments of the url:

  ```c#
  [Route("api/{language:regex(^[[a-z]]{{2}}-[[A-Z]]{{2}}$)}/[controller]")]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class BaseApiController: Controller
  {
  }

  public class ProductController : BaseApiController
  {
      //This will bind to /api/product/1 and /api/en-EN/product/1
      [HttpGet("{id}")]
      public IActionResult GetById(string id)
      {
          return new ObjectResult(new { foo = "bar" });
      }
  }
  ```
- A quick way of avoiding the base class without needing too much custom code is through the [web api compatibility shim](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/):

  - Add the package `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final"`
  - Add the shim conventions:

    ```c#
    services.AddMvc().AddWebApiConventions();
    ```
  - Make sure your controllers inherit from `ApiController`, which is added by the shim package
  - Define the routes including the culture parameter with te MapApiRoute overload:

    ```c#
    routes.MapWebApiRoute("apiLanguage", 
     "api/{language:regex(^[a-z]{{2}}-[A-Z]{{2}}$)}/{controller}/{id?}");

    routes.MapWebApiRoute("DefaultApi", 
     "api/{controller}/{id?}");
    ```
- The cleaner and better option would be creating and applying your own `IApplicationModelConvention` which takes care of adding the culture prefix to your attribute routes. This is out of the scope for this question, but I have implemented the idea for this [localization article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1314/aspnet-core-globalization-localization)

Then you need to create a new `IRequestCultureProvider` that will look at the request url and extract the culture from there (if provided).

> Once you upgrade to ASP .Net Core 1.1 you might avoid manually parsing the request url and extract the culture segment.
>
> I have checked the [implementation of `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing/RouteDataRequestCultureProvider.cs) in ASP.Net Core 1.1, and they use an HttpContext extension method `GetRouteValue(string)` for getting url segments inside the request provider:
>
> ```c#
> culture = httpContext.GetRouteValue(RouteDataStringKey)?.ToString();
> ```
>
> However I suspect (I haven't had a chance to try it yet) that this would only work when adding [middleware as MVC filters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/). That way your middleware runs after the Routing middleware, which is the one adding the `IRoutingFeature` into the HttpContext. As a quick test, adding the following middleware before UseMvc will get you no route data:
>
> ```c#
> app.Use(async (context, next) =>
> {
>     //always null
>     var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
>     await next();
> });
> ```

In order to implement the new `IRequestCultureProvider` you just need to:

- Search for the culture parameter in the request url path.
- If no parameter is found, return null. (If all the providers return null, the default culture will be used)
- If a culture parameter is found, return a new ProviderCultureResult with that culture.
- The [localization middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization/RequestLocalizationMiddleware.cs#L77) will fallback to the default one if it is not one of the supported cultures.

The implementation will look like:

```c#
public class UrlCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
{
    public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.Path;

        //Quick and dirty parsing of language from url path, which looks like "/api/de-DE/home"
        //This could be skipped after 1.1 if using the middleware as an MVC filter
        //since you will be able to just call the method GetRouteValue("culture") 
        //on the HttpContext and retrieve the route value
        var parts = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/');
        if (parts.Length < 3)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<ProviderCultureResult>(null);
        }
        var hasCulture = Regex.IsMatch(parts[2], @"^[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$");
        if (!hasCulture)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<ProviderCultureResult>(null);
        }

        var culture = parts[2];
        return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(culture));
    }
}
```

Finally enable the localization features including your new provider as the first one in the list of supported providers. As they are evaluated in order and the first one returning a not null result wins, your provider will take precedence and next will come [the default ones](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization/RequestLocalizationOptions.cs#L24) (query string, cookie and header).

```c#
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("en-GB")
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("en-GB")
    }
};
//Insert this at the beginning of the list since providers are evaluated in order until one returns a not null result
localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new UrlCultureProvider());

//Add request localization middleware
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions, new RequestCulture("en-US"));
```

Comment: Reading the culture parameter from url works fine but request to `/api/en-EN/products` results in a 404. Any clues?

Comment: Have a look at the edits, since web api style of controllers are now working out of the box via attribute routing, you might need to use the compatibility shim so you can define the routes using the routing table

Comment: That's a good question! According to the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) is still TBD, although the target for 1.0.0 is still this year 2016

Comment: I use AspNetCore version 1.0.0 and I try to use `var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();` BUT the result is null.
I have added `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;` to be able to compile. Any idea why the result is null ?

Comment: This is the regex for the global and specific culture:
Works for: "fr", "fr-FR", "en", "en-UK", ...
`var hasCulture = Regex.IsMatch(parts[2], @"^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})*$");`

Comment: @rdhainaut: Because `IRoutingFeature` is only added to the HttpContext, once then `RoutingMiddleware` is processed https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouterMiddleware.cs#L41-L49. But once it's processed (i.e. reigster UseRequestLocalization after `UseMvc`), it's to late to set the routing already handled the request

Comment: @rdhainaut Could you solve the htttpContext.GetRouteData() always null problem?

Comment: @SherleyDev nop i can't solve this problem because it comes from asp.net core.  If you want a complete solution, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170739/handle-culture-in-route-url-via-requestcultureproviders/38170740)