# ASP.NET Core Request Localization Options

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Here is my custom request culture provider which returns "en" as a default culture if no culture specified in url (for example `http://example.com/ru` or `http://example.com/en`).
My idea to show website on that language which is default in user's browser, so I'm looking a way how to determine it and return it instead of: return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en", "en"));

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("ru")                            
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
    {                    
        var pathSegments = context.Request.Path.Value.Split('/');
        if (pathSegments.Count() > 0)
        if (supportedCultures.Select(x => x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName).Contains((pathSegments[1])))
            return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(pathSegments[1], pathSegments[1]));
       return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en", "en"));
   }));
});
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can get `Accept-Language` header from the current `Request` and set default language. Your code should be something like this:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    //...

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
    {                    
       //...
       var userLangs = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
       var firstLang = userLangs.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
       var defaultLang = string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLang) ? "en" : firstLang;
       return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultLang, defaultLang));
   }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adem, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 35):

Another way to get the Accept-Language header with a framework call (ASP.NET Core):

`HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().AcceptLanguage`

Comment: Do not forget to order languages by its priority `q`, e.g. `OrderByDescending(x => x.Quality ?? 1)`.

Answer (score 8):

Inside your `public class Startup`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        //get client prefered language
        var userLangs = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
        var firstLang = userLangs.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();

        //set allowed alanguage
        var lang = "en"; //default
        switch (firstLang)
        {
            case "hy": //allowed
            case "ru": //allowed
                lang = firstLang; 
                break;
            default:
                //client language not supported
                lang = "en"; //use our default
                break;
        }

        //switch culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        //save for later use
        context.Items["ClientLang"] = lang;
        context.Items["ClientCulture"] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
        
        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        return next();
    });

    //... then goes app.UseMvc etc..

}
```

Answer (score 4):

as an additional option, Here is a full solution: [Handle culture in route (URL) via RequestCultureProviders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170739/handle-culture-in-route-url-via-requestcultureproviders)

as an option as well, here is a simplified code for CustomRequestCultureProvider:

```
options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
{
    var lang = context.Request.GetTypedHeaders().AcceptLanguage.FirstOrDefault()?.Value.Value ?? Constants.Languages.EN_US;

    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(lang, lang));

}));
```