# Localization in .NET Core API

Tags: api, .net-core, localization

I am trying to create localization Middleware in .NET Core API 2.2, I was following Microsoft's official instruction but I don't quite understand, how it works? I don't have views, so I must localize models with data annotations right?

I want to get language values through Accept-Language HTTP Header

here is my Middleware:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
     }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "ka-Ge" };
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
            .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
            .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
    }
```

Model:

```
 public class PersonsModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have Resx Files in Resourses folders: PersonsController.en-Us
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**please edit/improve/correct/adjust**

references:

https://damienbod.com/2015/10/21/asp-net-5-mvc-6-localization/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request

https://ml-software.ch/posts/writing-a-custom-request-culture-provider-in-asp-net-core-2-1

[ASP.NET Core Request Localization Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006690/asp-net-core-request-localization-options)

No, you need to apply somewhere (in your LocalizationMiddleware) IStringLocalizer, so you can create a getFunction with LocalizedString as return type.
That way you can use localization in your application wherever you want it.

Based on the culture-information of your current thread, and how you have defined your SharedResource, you'll get the corresponding value for the key.

You can find a solution below:

Checklist

1. Configure services in the DI container

a.  Register the service in
the Startup-method (see created separate classDIConfiguration)

b.  Configure and apply options of Localization in the
Configure-method

2. Define Localizationoptions (CustomRequestCultureProvider Class)
3. Build up your middleware in the appropriate project (business logic)
4. Define SharedResource.class and resx-files in the same project
5. Inject Middleware in business logic-class (handler)

1. Configure services in the DI container
   a.  Register the service in the Startup-method (see created separate classDIConfiguration)
   b.  Configure and apply options of Localization in the Configure-method

using …

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
                    });
            });

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
            DiConfiguration.ConfigureServices(Configuration, services);
            AutoMapperConfiguration.ConfigureAutoMapper(services);
            services.AddMediatorAndBehaviour();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[] { "nl", "en", "fr", "de" };
            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
                .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

              localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new  CustomRequestCultureProvider(localizationOptions));


            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
         // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
         // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        }
    }
 
using System;
using System.Text;
…
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

public static class DiConfiguration
    {
        public static void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Configure Database services
            services.AddDbContextPool<IsisContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("IsisDatabase")));

            services.AddScoped<IIsisUnitOfWork, IsisUnitOfWork>();
            …
            services.AddSingleton<ILocalizationMiddleware, LocalizationMiddleware>();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddOptions();

            …

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        }
}
```

2. Define Localizationoptions (CustomRequestCultureProvider Class)

   using …;

   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
   using System;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomRequestCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
{
public CustomRequestCultureProvider(RequestLocalizationOptions options)
{

```
        }

            public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
            {
                try
                {
                    var transmittedLanguageCode = httpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().AcceptLanguage;
                    string transmittedLanguageCodeString = transmittedLanguageCode.LastOrDefault().ToString();
                    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(transmittedLanguageCodeString));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(LanguagesDefinition.NL)); // scenario NL is the default
                }
            }
        }
```

3.  Build up your middleware in the appropriate project (business logic)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

namespace ….Business.LocalizationService
{
    public interface ILocalizationMiddleware
    {
        public LocalizedString GetLocalizedString(string keyForResourceTable);
    }
}

using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ….Business.LocalizationService
{
    public class LocalizationMiddleware : ILocalizationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;

        public LocalizationMiddleware(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
        }

        public LocalizedString GetLocalizedString(string keyForResourceTable) { return localizer[keyForResourceTable]; }
    }
}
```

4; Define (SharedResource.class optional) Resources-folder and resx-files in the same project

[image: Resources-folder withing your project]

5. Inject Middleware in business logic-class (handler)

```
public class SomeClass
    {        
        public AdvancedSearchResultDtoToCsvMap(ILocalizationMiddleware localizationMiddleware)
        {
            Map(m => m.Id).Ignore();
            Map(m => m.ArticleCode).Index(0).Name(localizationMiddleware.GetLocalizedString("articlecode").Value);
            Map(m => m.Fullname).Index(1).Name(localizationMiddleware.GetLocalizedString("fullname").Value);
           …
        }
    }
```