# FromHeader attribute with multiple names

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to use the FromHeader attribute with multiple names (e.g. for multi-language support) to the same model.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromHeader(Name="Test-NLD"),FromHeader(Name="Test-ENG")] string Test)
```

You can not use multiple FromHeader attributes with another name to the same model (error CS0579, Duplicate 'FromHeader' attribute).

What is the best way to resolve this? I use Swagger, so it would be nice if the Swagger documentation is still correct.

Comment: Do you need to keep the header keys in that format, or can you make one header for the language selection and another for the value?

Comment: I would like to keep the header keys in format if that is possible.

Comment: Do you have a small fixed list of languages you support?

Comment: For now the only languages supported are NL-nl and EN-us.

Answer (score 3):

In the short term, you'll need to make two different parameters on your action, one binding to each possible Header key.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
    [FromHeader(Name="Test-NLD")] string testNld,
    [FromHeader(Name="Test-ENG")] string testEng)
```

`FromHeader` doesn't accept multiple entries on a single parameter, or wildcards.

*For now*, if you're only going to support 2 languages, you *might* be able to squeak by with this solution. It's, understandably, very maintenance intensive and the definition of "Technical Debt".

---

ASP.Net and Swagger both work their best when the Header Keys are static. It's not possible to document "You need supply a header called `Test-*`, where `*` is 'NLD' or 'ENG'."

In the future, I still very much recommend that you split the choice of language into its own key. You could even use the "standard" [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
    [FromHeader(Name="Accept-Language")] string clientLanguages,
    [FromHeader(Name="Test")] string test)
```

Accept-Languages is written so that it's expected the client gives you a CSV of languages they want, in priority order. You select the first one that you support, and inform the client of the selection with the Content-Language response header.

There are also more elegant methods to get the Accept-Language header, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006690/asp-net-core-request-localization-options).