# Asp.Net core get RouteData value from url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm wokring on a new Asp.Net core mvc app. I defined a route with a custom constraint, which sets current app culture from the url. I'm trying to manage localization for my app by creating a custom `IRequestCultureProvider` which looks like this :

```cs
    public class MyCustomRequestCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
    {
        public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var language = httpContext.GetRouteValue("language");
    
            var result = new ProviderCultureResult(language, language);
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }
```

My `MyCustomRequestCultureProvider` is hit on every request, which is ok. My problem is that in the MVC pipeline, `DetermineProviderCultureResult` method from my provider is hit before the routing process, so `httpContext.GetRouteValue("language")` always return null.

In previous version of MVC, I had the possiblity to manually process my url through the routing process by doing this

```
var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(wrapper);
var language = routeData.GetValue("language")
```

I can't find a way to do the same thing in the new framewrok right now. Also, I want to use the route data to find out my langugae, analysing my url string with some string functions to find the language is not an option.

Comment: This [question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829426/optionally-override-request-culture-via-url-route-in-an-asp-net-core-1-0-applica/35970676#35970676) might help

Comment: @nboisvert Could you solve this problem?

Comment: @SherleyDev see my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do this, and the ASP.Net team hasn't decided to implement this functionality yet.  `IRoutingFeature` is only available after MVC has completed the request.

I was able to put together a solution that should work for you though.  This will setup the routes you're passing into `UseMvc()` as well as all attribute routing in order to populate `IRoutingFeature`. After that is complete, you can access that class via `httpContext.GetRouteValue("language");`.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // setup routes
        app.UseGetRoutesMiddleware(GetRoutes);
    
        // add localization
        var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US")
        };
        requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
        requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Add(
            new MyCustomRequestCultureProvider()
        );
        app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);
    
        // add mvc
        app.UseMvc(GetRoutes);
    }
```

Moved the routes to a delegate (for re-usability), same file/class:

```cs
    private readonly Action<IRouteBuilder> GetRoutes =
        routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "custom",
                template: "{language=fr-FR}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        };
```

**Add new middleware:**

```cs
    public static class GetRoutesMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseGetRoutesMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes)
        {
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
            }
    
            var routes = new RouteBuilder(app)
            {
                DefaultHandler = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MvcRouteHandler>(),
            };
            configureRoutes(routes);
            routes.Routes.Insert(0, AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(app.ApplicationServices));
            var router = routes.Build();
    
            return app.UseMiddleware<GetRoutesMiddleware>(router);
        }
    }
    
    public class GetRoutesMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly IRouter _router;
    
        public GetRoutesMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IRouter router)
        {
            this.next = next;
            _router = router;
        }
    
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var context = new RouteContext(httpContext);
            context.RouteData.Routers.Add(_router);
    
            await _router.RouteAsync(context);
    
            if (context.Handler != null)
            {
                httpContext.Features[typeof (IRoutingFeature)] = new RoutingFeature()
                {
                    RouteData = context.RouteData,
                };
            }
    
            // proceed to next...
            await next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

You may have to define this class as well...

```cs
    public class RoutingFeature : IRoutingFeature
    {
        public RouteData RouteData { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: wow only being able to edit comments for 5 mins is a pain! this is what I meant to say: I needed to access a parameter in some other middleware and this did the job for me with little to no modification! 5* would use again

Answer (score 4):

Based on Ashley Lee's answer, here is an optimized approach that prevents duplicate route configuration.

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       // setup routes
       var mvcRouter = BuildMvcRouter(app, routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "custom",
               template: "{language=fr-FR}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // add route data initialization middleware
        app.Use(next => SetRouteData(next, mvcRouter));

        // add localization middleware
        var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US")
        };
        requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
        requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Add(
            new MyCustomRequestCultureProvider()
        );
        app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);

        // add mvc routing middleware
        app.UseRouter(mvcRouter);
    }

This depends on the following two methods that must be added to the StartUp class:

    private static IRouter BuildMvcRouter(IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes)
    {
        if (app == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        if (configureRoutes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configureRoutes));

        app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MiddlewareFilterBuilder>().ApplicationBuilder = app.New();
        var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(app)
        {
            DefaultHandler = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MvcRouteHandler>()
        };
        configureRoutes(routeBuilder);
        routeBuilder.Routes.Insert(0, AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(app.ApplicationServices));

        return routeBuilder.Build();
    }

    private static RequestDelegate SetRouteData(RequestDelegate next, IRouter router)
    {
        return async context =>
        {
            var routeContext = new RouteContext(context);
            await router.RouteAsync(routeContext);

            if (routeContext.Handler != null)
            {
                context.Features[typeof(IRoutingFeature)] = new RoutingFeature
                {
                    RouteData = routeContext.RouteData
                };
            }

            await next(context);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been made easier with the addition of the Endpoint Routing feature.
This article explains how to do it using the Endpoint Routing feature https://aregcode.com/blog/2019/dotnetcore-understanding-aspnet-endpoint-routing/

```cs
    var endpointFeature = context.Features[typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IEndpointFeature)]
                                           as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IEndpointFeature;

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Endpoint endpoint = endpointFeature?.Endpoint;

    //Note: endpoint will be null, if there was no
    //route match found for the request by the endpoint route resolver middleware
    if (endpoint != null)
    {
        var routePattern = (endpoint as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteEndpoint)?.RoutePattern
                                                                                   ?.RawText;

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + endpoint.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Route Pattern: {routePattern}");
        Console.WriteLine("Metadata Types: " + string.Join(", ", endpoint.Metadata));
    }
```