# ASP.Net core- getting routetemplate value from middleware

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a middleware that is called for every request to my APIs. I want to log the route template along with the duration of the request from this middleware. How to get route template in my middleware code? Route template is something like "/products/{productId}".

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I got it working. I get the route template inside my filter OnActionExecuting method and add it to HttpContext. Later I access this from HttpContext inside my middleware, since I can access HttpContext inside the middleware.

```
public class LogActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public LogActionFilter()
        {
        }
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {

        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Items.Add("RouteTemplate", context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually achieve this quite easily with ASP.NET Core 3.0+ by getting the `ControllerActionDescriptor` from the `context` in a middleware:

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    Endpoint endpointBeingHit = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
    ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = endpointBeingHit?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();

    this.logger.LogInformation(
        "Matched route template '{template}'",
        actionDescriptor?.AttributeRouteInfo.Template);

    await next();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

it's work for me:

```
(context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint as RouteEndpoint)?.RoutePattern.RawText;
```

Where context is HttpContext

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to get the route data from a custom middleware because it is created by MVC middleware which generally happens to be the last middleware to be executed in the ASP.NET Core pipeline.

If you want to log the request and response in your middleware as below,

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var requestBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
        var originalRequestBody = context.Request.Body;

        await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestBodyStream);
        requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var url = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(context.Request);
        var requestBodyText = new StreamReader(requestBodyStream).ReadToEnd();
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, 1, $"REQUEST METHOD: {context.Request.Method}, REQUEST BODY: {requestBodyText}, REQUEST URL: {url}", null, _defaultFormatter);

        requestBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        context.Request.Body = requestBodyStream;

        await next(context);
                var bodyStream = context.Response.Body;

    var responseBodyStream = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = responseBodyStream;

    await _next(context);

    responseBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var responseBody = new StreamReader(responseBodyStream).ReadToEnd();
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, 1, $"RESPONSE LOG: {responseBody}", null, _defaultFormatter);
    responseBodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await responseBodyStream.CopyToAsync(bodyStream);
    }
```

However, if you are really interested in route data, there is very nice SO answer to implement a get routes miidleware [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505184/asp-net-core-get-routedata-value-from-url)

Other alternative approach would be to use [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#action-filters)for request/response logging.

Comment: Your code example logs actual request url. I wanted to log the route template. that is instead of /products/product123 I wanted to log /products/{productId}. However, I'm able to get this using Action Filter. Thanks for that info.