# How can I get a request path without any variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, prometheus, httpcontext, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create some metrics using prometheus and I'd like to capture metrics on each endpoint without having to always having to setup something specific for each endpoint (pain and risk of forgetting to do it if we were to ever add additional endpoints). Most examples I've seen just create middleware can capture `httpContext.Request.Path`. The problem with this is in a REST API, there could be one or more unique values in that path. For example `/v1/users/1234` - 1234 is the user ID which will be different for every user. The result being that I now end up with separate metric for every user which isn't what I want.

How can I remove variables from the path so that I can narrow this down to just the actual endpoint?

I thought of maybe just capturing the route template (e.g. `/v1/users/{userId}`) which seems like it could be done, but I can't quite figure out how to retrieve that from `HttpContext` in middleware. I tried `GetRouteData()` but that only has a dictionary of the variable names and the value which isn't enough to extract from the actual path. Is there an object/service somewhere in DI I could grab in the Ctor that would give me access to that info? TIA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380514/asp-net-core-getting-routetemplate-value-from-middleware (the last answer seems to target endpoint routing)