# .Net Core : How to get RouteData from URL string?

Tags: c#, routes, .net-core

In a .Net core Controller, I would like to parse a custom URL (string) to get its routeDatas.

In .Net 4.5 this code do the job. What is the equivalent in .Net Core ?

```
var routeData = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(
    new HttpContextWrapper(
        new HttpContext(
            new HttpRequest(null, link.Url, ""), 
            new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StringWriter())
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Beedjees - did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

the dotnet core way of doing it is to use ParsePathByEndpointName method of LinkParser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkparserendpointnameaddressextensions.parsepathbyendpointname?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_LinkParserEndpointNameAddressExtensions_ParsePathByEndpointName_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_LinkParser_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_PathString_

```
 var values = parser.ParsePathByEndpointName("default", "/Home/Index");
 var controllerName = values["controller"];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can access it from `RouteData` property in [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.1#properties) and its sub-class.

**Edit:**

Okay, then you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505184/asp-net-core-get-routedata-value-from-url).

Depending on your scenario, you maybe want to handle the parameter in a different way.

Comment: This method return the RouteData for the executing action. But I want to get the routeDatas for a custom url (of my webSite) passing by parameter